# Change account in Your Phone app

Tags: windows-10, android, sync, user-accounts, your-phone

This is my setup:

1. I have a PC with two linked Microsoft accounts - my work account and my personal account. It has Windows 10 Enterprise, version 2004.
2. My wife has a PC where we both have our personal Microsoft accounts. It has also Windows 10, version 2004 installed, but it is a Home license.
3. And lastly, I have an Android phone with my Microsoft work and personal accounts. It is a Google Pixel 2 (I know, quite old, but it works very well) with Android 10 with the latest updates and security patches.

Now, I wanted to try out the Your Phone application. I am trying to sync it with both of my PCs via my personal account. It works perfectly on my wife's PC. However, I cannot get it to work on my PC. I have a suspicion that the Your Phone app is automatically picking the work account and I cannot find a way how to switch it to my personal account.

The displayed name of the synced phone in the Your Phone app (in my PC) is correct. However, nothing gets synced - neither pictures, nor messages, nor notifications. I have tried to Repair, Reset and even re-install the Your Phone app (via PowerShell). Everytime when I start it, it just writes that *Things are getting ready* and suddenly I see the app with no synced content. There is no pop-up to choose which account should be used.

How do I check and/or change which account is being used?